# How to add fields for the form with the 'carrierwave' gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm familiar with code like

```
Video.create(title: 'title')
```

which if you added to this you could add more values when making an entry

```
Video.create(title: 'title', value: 'value')
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do this with the 'carrierwave' gem but because the form was auto generated I'm not sure how to adjust it.  For example how would I add a 'value' value that would get added to the Videos table, assuming the column exists.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@video) do |f| %>
  <% if @video.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@video.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this video from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @video.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :file %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :file %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Video</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', videos_path %>
```

Videos Controller

```
def new
  @video = Video.new
end

def create
  @video = Video.new(video_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @video.save
      format.html { redirect_to @video, notice: 'Video was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @video }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @video.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to store the uploaded video in the `value` field right?
In that case you can use `value` as the name of the file field. Also make sure you have mounted the uploader like below :

```
 mount_uploader :value, VideoUploader
```

where VideoUploader is the name of the uploader.

refer [how to upload videos using Carrierwave](https://railsblogs.rohityadav.in/2017/11/uploading-any-media-file-with-carrier.html)